# How do I show that a subset is open iff its preimage is open under a continuous surjection?

Tags: general-topology

How do I show that under a continuous surjection $f:X\to Y$ between compact, Hausdorff spaces, a subset $U$ is open in $Y$ if the preimage of $U$ is open in $X$? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show that $f$ maps closed sets to closed sets.  Use the fact that a subset of a compact Hausdorff space is closed if and only if it is compact.

Answer (score 1):

Take $U \subset Y$. If $f^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X$ then we have that $f^{-1}(Y\setminus U)  = X\setminus f^{-1}(U)$ is closed in $X$. Since it's closed on a compact set it's compact itself. So $f( f^{-1}(Y\setminus U)$ is compact and since $Y$ is a Hausdorff space we have $f( f^{-1}(Y\setminus U))$ is closed. Notice that $Y\setminus U = f( f^{-1}(Y\setminus U))$ because $f$ is surjective and therefore $Y\setminus U$ is closed, that is, $U$ is open in $Y$.